# Boomerang: Unable to load libQtGUI

Tags: c, linux, gdb, boomerang

I installed boomerang on Fedora 17 and when executing ./boomerang-gui I get:

```
./boomerang-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui_debug.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director
```

I did a "sudo yum install qt-x11", but QT is already installed.

Comment: Looks like you need the development package. [This site](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libQtGui_debug.so&submit=Search+...&system=fedora+17&arch=i686) points to [`qt-debuginfo`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/17/i386/debug/qt-debuginfo-4.8.2-4.fc17.i686.html) package. Try looking it up and installing using `yum`

Comment: @another.anon.coward, I installed qt-debuginfo.i686 1:4.8.2-4.fc17 and I'm still getting the same error message.

Comment: Hmm it could be possible that boomerang links to older version of Qt. Can you check the requirements for building boomerang? Where are you building it from?

Comment: @another.anon.coward, I downloaded the binary release from here and untarred it: http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/download.php (boomerang-linux-alpha-0.3)  I installed libgc separately.

Comment: It looks like a fairly old library. Maybe the library names have changed in Qt. You could try to check where exactly this linking is happening & update that file. I will try to build it sometime (not now... too late in the night already :) ) & update if you don't get any response

Comment: @another.anon.coward, Thanks.  I did see this in my environment variables "QTLIB=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/lib"  I set it to qt4 but still getting the same error message.

Comment: This looks to be a fairly old build. I tried to run this on Linux Mint 12, but it failed with same error. The library which it depends on is probably older version of Qt library. As a hack, I created a soft link to QtGUI library on my system as `libQtGui_debug.so.4` in lib/ folder under boomerang (& same of QtCore which you will encounter after first hack). Export lib/ folder as `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and run `boomerang-gui`. The application did come up, but not all UI elements were functional.

Comment: You can check the library dependency using `ldd` for both `boomerang` and `boomerang-gui`, if you see for any library the entry is "not found" then that library is missing & path to that library needs to be provided. Maybe you can work w/o a GUI if possible i.e. using `boomerang` through command line. Another alternative would be, to get the source which is available as mentioned on the site & try to build it. There is a good possibility that source may not build as is and some changes to the source code may be required. Good luck!

Comment: @another.anon.coward, Thanks.  I ended up just using the command line tool.  That worked fine.

Comment: I got the GUI running (although it doesn't seem very functional) by creating two links: `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 /usr/lib/libQtGui_debug.so.4` and `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 /usr/lib/libQtCore_debug.so.4`. (Running Ubuntu and installed Qt with `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui`)

Answer (score 4):

From the error:

```
./boomerang-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui_debug.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It looks like the `boomerang-gui` has been linked with debug version of Qt library. So creating a symbolic link like below works.

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 /usr/lib/libQtGui_debug.so.4
```

and

```bash
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 /usr/lib/libQtCore_debug.so.4
```

Alternatively, from the ubuntu synaptic package manager you can install debug version of Qt library. (`libqt4-dbg`)

Comment: On Ubuntu 64 bits, you need the 32 bits version of the lib: `apt install libqtgui4:i386` for boomerang to work.